# Publish debuggable apk to Google Play

Tags: android

Currently I am using Cordova/Phone Gap to build my apk. For some reason (we are working on it) only debuggable works. It it possible to upload it to the Google Play store? (Ubuntu/Windows)

Comment: It is probably possible but I think you should focus on `why` it  only works on debug version. Depending on your app nature, it can cause a lot of damage / issues using debug version.

Comment: as per i experienced you can not upload debuggable apk to google play. It showed apk error to me. Could you do it somehow? @LawrenceChoy

Comment: You should find the reason why your realease version not work! :)

Comment: Just because it's not the answer you want doesn't mean it isn't helpful.  These people are telling you the best approach to solve your problem, don't blame them if they don't want to help you to do it wrong.